# php script just stops even with set_time_limit(0)

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked at like 10 other posts with people who seem to have the same problem as me in, most suggest putting `set_time_limit(0);`. But even with that no matter what script I run, always after around 9-10 minutes it just stops.

I have tried so many combinations of the below 3 variables, setting them to `-1`, `0`, `9999999`; just always stops. It was not so long ago, I had the exact same script below run over night. And just one day I have this problem with any script.

I’m 100% sure it’s stopping before its finished, and it’s not stopping due to error. Because any of my scripts now stop at the same app run time.

Extremely frustrated, any help will be much appreciated.

In php.ini:

```
max_input_time = -1
max_execution_time = 0
set_time_limit = 0
```

Another scripts: (also stops after 10 minutes)

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
function categoryinsert($english, $name, $keywords, $language)
{
    if(!$english)
    {
        echo "no english recieved! in categoryinsert<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    else if(!$name)
    {
        echo "no name recieved! in categoryinsert<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    else if(!$language)
    {
        echo "no language recieved! in categoryinsert<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER***", "************");
    mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
    mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "db***");

    $qwry = "INSERT INTO `categories` (english, name, keywords, language) values ('$english','$name','$keywords','$language');";
            $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $qwry);
            //Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.[".$qwry."]<p>"
            //. "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
            //. ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>"; 

            mysqli_close($DBConnect);
}
function checkfor($english, $lang)
{
    $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER***", "************");
    mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
    mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "db***");

    $qwry = "SELECT * FROM `categories` where english = '$english' and language = '$lang';";
            $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $qwry);

            $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);

            mysqli_close($DBConnect);

            if($Row) return true;
            else return false;
}
function categoryupdate($keywords, $language, $english)
{
if(!$english)
    {
        echo "no english recieved! in categoryupdate<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    else if(!$keywords)
    {
        echo "no keywords recieved! in categoryupdate<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    else if(!$language)
    {
        echo "no language recieved! in categoryupdate<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER***", "************");
    mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
    mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "db***");

    $qwry = "UPDATE `categories` set keywords = '$keywords' where language = '$language' and language = '$language';";
            $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $qwry)
            Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.[".$qwry."]<p>"
            . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
            . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>"; 

            mysqli_close($DBConnect);
}
function translatekeywords($keywords, $tolang)
{

    if(!$keywords)
    {
        echo "no keywords recieved! in translatekeywords<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    else if(!$tolang)
    {
        echo "no tolang recieved! in translatekeywords<br />";
        return 0;
    }
    $parts = explode(", ", $keywords);
    $count = 0;
    $out = "";

    while($parts[$count])
    {
        if(($count != 0) and ($result)) $out = $out . ", ";
        $result = translate($parts[$count], 'eng', $tolang);
        if($result) $out = $out . $result;
        $count++;
    }

    return $out;
}
include '../functions.php';

$DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USER***", "************");
    mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
    mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "db***");


            $qwry = "SELECT english, keywords FROM `categories` where language = 'eng' order by name ASC;";
            $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $qwry)
            Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.[".$qwry."]<p>"
            . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
            . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>"; 

            $count = 0;
            $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);

            do
            {
                $categories[$count] = $Row;             
                echo $count.') ['.$categories[$count][0].']['.$categories[$count][1].']<br />';
                $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);
                $count++;
            }while($Row);

            $qwry = "SELECT ISO3 FROM `languages` order by name ASC;";
            $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $qwry)
            Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.[".$qwry."]<p>"
            . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
            . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>"; 

            $count = 0;
            $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);

            do
            {
                $languages[$count] = $Row[0];
                $Row = mysqli_fetch_row($QueryResult);
                echo '['.$languages[$count].']<br />';
                $count++;
            }while($Row);

            $lcount = 0;
            do
            {
                if($languages[$lcount] != 'eng')
                {
                    $ccount = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        if(!checkfor($categories[$ccount][0], $languages[$lcount]))
                        {
                            $name = translate($categories[$ccount][0], 'eng', $languages[$lcount]);
                            if($categories[$ccount][1]) $keywords = translatekeywords($categories[$ccount][1],$languages[$lcount]);
                            categoryinsert($categories[$ccount][0], $name, $keywords, $languages[$lcount]);
                        }
                        $ccount++;
                    }while($categories[$ccount]);
                }

            $lcount++;
            }while($languages[$lcount]);

mysqli_close($DBConnect);
echo "FINISHED! [$lcount] languages proccessed";
?>
```

The script:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
include 'functions.php'; 

function insertsentence($sentence, $lang, $id, $user)
{
    if(($lang == 'epo') and (strlen($sentence) < 255) )
    {
        $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx_userx", "xxxxxxx!");
        mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
        mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "xxxxx_main");

            $insertqwry = "INSERT INTO `sentences` (sentence, user, id, language) VALUES ('".withslashes($sentence)."', '".withslashes($user)."', '".withslashes($id)."', '".withslashes($lang)."');";

        $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $insertqwry) ;
        //Or die("<p>Unable to execute the query.[".$insertqwry."]<p>"
        //. "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
        //. ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>"; 

        mysqli_close($DBConnect);
return 1;
    }

}

$myFile = "sentences_detailed.csv"; 
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$s = fread($fh, 3);
if ($s != pack('CCC',0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf)) {
    // bom not found, rewind file
    fseek($fh, 0, SEEK_SET);
}

$count = 0;
ob_start();
do
{

    $line = preg_replace('/^\p{Z}+|\p{Z}+$/u', '', withslashes(trim(fgets($fh))));
    $parts = explode("  ", $line);
        $id = $parts[0];
        $lang = $parts[1];
        $sentence = withslashes($parts[2]);
        $user = withslashes($parts[3]);
        $note = "";


        if ((!$line) or ($line == "") or ($line == "!"))
        {
            echo ($count-1)." entries were processed<br />";
            echo "done<br />";
            exit();
        }



                if ($sentence != "!" )
                {
                    if (insertsentence($sentence, $lang, $id, $user))
                    echo "!";
                }

        ob_flush();
        flush();

    $count++;

    echo ".";

}while($line);

fclose($fh);
mysqli_close($DBConnect);

echo ($count-1)." entries were processed<br />";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** No matter what script I run, or how simple it always stops after about 10 minutes. So I doubt it’s anything to do with the code in my script. So I'll add that my web server I’m running scripts on, is on [Bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com).

Comment: Seems like your standard server timeout. A handy workaround is printing something to the page every once in a while and by that keeping the connection alive.

Comment: im printing "."s aren't i?

Comment: Did you check the PHP log...?

Comment: Looking at your code, `insertsentence` does not return anything and therefore the "." isn't printed.

Comment: true. I moved the echo "." to somewhere it will be printed  and restated the script. now to wait 9-10 minutes...

Comment: Put a p tag before `$QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $insertqwry) ;` that says Connection Open, then a new p tag before `return 1` that says Connection Close, so you know if the query completes.  Then the same for File Open and FileClose.  If you never see output, you'll figure out where your hung

Comment: Connecting and disconnecting on every insert like that and not using prepared statements and/or transactions is grossly, Grossly inefficient, this doesn't directly answer your question so i am using a comment.

Comment: @Victory I think hes doing it this way because of an `INSERT` but now that I  look at it, does mySQL allow reopening a connection once its closed?

Comment: @ECarterYoung - i don't understand your logic, there are many optimizations that would work just fine with `INSERT`. Please explain.

Comment: Instead of looping, he's Running one insert at a time, then reopening, then one insert etc.  You are correct, but hes doing it this way as count is incremented w/ each insert, which I agree is inefficient

Comment: do you for some reason have safe mode enabled?!

Comment: in php.ini --> sql.safe_mode = Off

Comment: withslashes just adds backslashes to halfquotes

Comment: @E Carter Young i would like to try your suggestion but im afraid im not sure what a "p tag" is. mysqli_ping?

Comment: @user1397417 - not sql.safe_mode just safe_mode

Comment: i dont seem to have a "safe_mode" in my php.ini. should i add it as Off?

Comment: @user1397417 - if you are using php < 5.4 add this to your ini:
`safe_mode = Off` and `safe_mode_gid = Off` then restart apache

Comment: Can you tell from a shell if this script is using a lot of CPU resources?  You may want to check with BlueHost, maybe they have a monitor that is killing off your script after 10 minutes of heavy runtime as a safety measure.

Comment: it is a shared webserver and i am not able to restart apache. but i have added those to my php.ini.  Also added a script i am currently using to my question. because the former is 20 days old and im not using it now. It has the exact same problem of stopping after 10 min

Comment: Can you try running your script on a local pc via a local apache server like appserv. I know that it will take much more time, but you are free to change ini and apache settings as well as use task manager to monitor resources and limits (if you are using windows). I have used appserv to run a HUGE amount of inserts and updates for more than 30 minutes and worked fine... This can be your last solution at the end of the day

Comment: @user1397417 - set_time_limit can't work with safe_mode enabled and that's why I am asking, however, I doubt that a shared hosting will have safe_mode enabled for default. Therefore, there should be something else causing this issue. I would have asked your hosting provider for a feedback if I were in your shoes

Comment: i have submitted a ticket about this in the past and i don't recall ever getting a reply, but i submitted another anyway.

Comment: Did you try to create a script which just has a simple loop outputing some characters every 10 seconds for 20 minutes. IF this process finishes, it is most likely some error in the code. If it does not finish, it might be some "watchdog" process on the server host which kills processes which it thinks might hang.

Comment: @user1397417 an html P Tag, sorry I just saw this... The idea is to write the "debug echoes" to the browser using paragraph tags and then remove them once you get the script debugged

Comment: well i have tried everything suggested so far, but none of the changes fix the stopping problem. And yet to receive a response from bluehost.

Comment: yep they kill the process after 10 minutes of run time. unless i pay for a dedicated ip

Comment: "received" is misspelled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is its a limitation bluehost has set to my account. Heres the response he gave me:

```
...
The Dedicated IP (+$3.33 per month) will increase the limits on the account.


    The following it the limits on how the server will kill processes with and without the Dedicated IP on the account: 

                                    With a Dedicated IP         Without Dedicated IP
Apache/Web (HTML/PHP/Downloads)     12 hours                    10 minutes
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) function of PHP, with this you can execute your loop continuously - I know this is not the best and final solution but this might helpful to you :)

See this first [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#54841)

Comment: did you not look at my script i posted? I am using flush. And it looks like im using it the same way your example is.

Comment: Have you included sleep(2); function?

Comment: no i have not, the file is millions of lines long, so i would rather not make it take longer. how do you think this sleep() function will help?

Comment: using sleep() or usleep() is a good idea to load down your server if processes are so heavy - atleast you can try with it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas.

First your code has these calls to a function called `withslashes()` which I assume is a custom function designed to add slashes (aka: escape) values to quotes & other characters But you are using MySQLi calls, right? Then why not avoid reinventing the wheel and just use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) which is part of the MySQLi extensions?

Also, I added [`mysqli_free_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php) which “Frees the memory associated with a result.” Which can’t hurt even if the result of your query is just an acknowledgement that the query ran.

And I added a [`sleep()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) value of ` second to at least throttle the process a bit to give your server room to breath.

The whole goal is to use built-in PHP functions to avoid using more RAM than necessary when running MySQL queries & pausing the script by 1 second to give it breathing room.

Here is a refactored version of `insertsentence()` using the first set of ideas to improve performance:

```
function insertsentence($sentence, $lang, $id, $user) {

    if (($lang == 'epo') and (strlen($sentence) < 255)) {
        $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx_userx", "xxxxxxx!");
        mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
        mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "xxxxx_main");

        $insertqwry = "INSERT INTO `sentences` (sentence, user, id, language)"
                    . " VALUES ('$sentence', '$user', '$id', '$lang');"
                    ;

        // Escape the query.
        $insertqwry = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect, $insertqwry);

        $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $insertqwry) ;
    
        // Free the result set.
        mysqli_free_result($QueryResult);

        mysqli_close($DBConnect);
 
        // Sleep for 1 second.
        sleep(1);
 
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

But why not use [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to make full use of the prepared statements capability of MySQLi? Then you no longer need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` because prepared statements basically handle all of that.

With that in mind, here is another refactored version of `insertsentence()` which uses `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`:

```
function insertsentence($sentence, $lang, $id, $user) {

    if (($lang == 'epo') and (strlen($sentence) < 255)) {
        $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx_userx", "xxxxxxx!");
        mysqli_set_charset($DBConnect, "utf8");
        mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, "xxxxx_main");

        $insertqwry = "INSERT INTO `sentences` (sentence, user, id, language)"
                    . " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
                    ;

        // Bind the values to the statement.
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insertqwry, 'ssis', $sentence, $user, $id, $lang);

        $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $insertqwry) ;

        // Free the result set.
        mysqli_free_result($QueryResult);

        mysqli_close($DBConnect);

        // Sleep for 1 second.
        sleep(1);
 
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Note the `'ssds'` in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`. Each letter determines the types of your 4 values. So in this case it is string (`sentence`), string (`user`), integer (`id`), string (`language`) which is my best guesses based on the data you’re giving me.

Comment: is mysqli_free_result really supposed to go after mysqli_close?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your script is limited  by the server.  I think you can change this in php.ini.